# JS console log value in array of object attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to log to console whether an array of objects contains a specific value on a specific attribute of one of these such objects.

in Python this is as simple as

```py
print(val in [x['attribute'] for x in objects])
```

In JS, I think the inclusion operation should function as

```
objects.map(x=>x.attribute).includes(val);
// console.log(objects.map(x=>x.attribute).includes(val).toString());
```

From reading, I've come to understand that raw booleans cannot be logged so they must be converted to string first.

the above is neither logging "true" or "false". So am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I would post your test data

Comment: Is `val` (and thus `.attribute`) a primitive value such as a string or number? Or is it an object? `.includes()` does a `===` comparison, so for objects it will be comparing object reference and thus may not do what you want.

Comment: Your code works fine when you use `console.log(objects.map(x=>x.attribute).includes(val).toString());` but you commented it out

Comment: Great question, `obj.attribute` should be a string but due to design decisions beyond my control, when this attribute is effectively null, the value will be integer of 0.

Comment: It's not commented in prod

Comment: I would post example data as when I put together an example array of objects, your code works.

Comment: In Python I would probably write `val in map(lambda x: x['attribute'], objects)` rather than using a list comprehension. List comprehensions are syntactic sugar for `list(map(filter(...)))`, but you don't need the `list` or the `filter` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct if you want to log *whether an array of objects contains a specific value on a specific attribute of one of these such objects*.

Whether the object contains a value returns a boolean.

Are you trying to log the objects that have an attribute that contain a specific value? If so, I would use filter in stead of map, like this:

`objects.filter(x => x. attribute.includes(val))`.